# Configuring JsonNetSerializer and JsonNetBodyDeserializer using Nancy TinyIoC

Tags: c#, json.net, nancy, tinyioc

I am a noob to Nancy.  I have been using it as a framework to produce a REST API.  I am familiar with Json.NET so I've been playing with the `Nancy.Serialization.JsonNet` package.

**My goal: to customize the behavior (i.e. change the settings) of the `JsonNetSerializer` and `JsonNetBodyDeserializer`.**

Specifically I'd like to incorporate the following settings...

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Formatting.Indented };
settings.Converters.Add( new StringEnumConverter { AllowIntegerValues = false, CamelCaseText = true } );
```

I wanted to perform this customization using the builtin TinyIoC container to avoid the inheritance chain and limit potential issues arising from any changes in the `Nancy.Serialization.JsonNet` package.

*NOTE: As a temporary workaround, I have leveraged inheritance to create `CustomJsonNetSerializer` and `CustomJsonNetBodyDeserializer`.*

I have tried several approaches to incorporate this configuration at least for the `JsonNetSerializer`.  I've not tried configuring the `JsonNetBodyDeserializer` using the TinyIoC yet.  I imagine it will be done similarly.  All the work I've tried is in my `CustomNancyBootstrapper` (which inherits from `DefaultNancyBootstrapper`).

Most successful approach so far: override `ConfigureApplicationContainer`

```
protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer( TinyIoCContainer container )
{
    base.ConfigureApplicationContainer( container );

    // probably don't need both registrations, and I've tried only keeping one or the other
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Formatting.Indented };
    settings.Converters.Add( new StringEnumConverter { AllowIntegerValues = false, CamelCaseText = true } );
    container.Register( new JsonNetSerializer( JsonSerializer.CreateDefault( settings ) ) );
    container.Register<ISerializer>( new JsonNetSerializer( JsonSerializer.CreateDefault( settings ) ) );
}
```

I have traced the code and watched the `JsonNetSerializer(JsonSerializer serializer)` constructor in the JsonNet package.

Potential problem: I noticed the constructor is called twice. I did not expect this behavior.

The first time everything is just right - my customization is added and registered properly. But, then the second time happens and the types are re-registered, without the settings customization. The re-registration appears to replace the original registration losing my settings customization.

The call stack the second time the constructor is called shows that it is called during `GetEngine` and `GetEngineInternal` which seems to try to build a `NancyEngine` (I am using the self-host package so this happens in program.cs -- `using(var host = new NancyHost(uri))` ).

Seems like I either need to tell Nancy not to do something or I need to hook in to a later part in the chain.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Typically the way to solve this in Nancy is to implement your own JSON Serializer like so:

```
public sealed class CustomJsonSerializer : JsonSerializer
{
    public CustomJsonSerializer()
    {
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter
        {
            AllowIntegerValues = false, 
            CamelCaseText = true
        });
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    }
}
```

Here you can override all the settings.

Then you can register it, I do this by using `IRegistrations`

```
public class JsonRegistration : IRegistrations
{
    public IEnumerable<TypeRegistration> TypeRegistrations
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TypeRegistration(typeof(JsonSerializer), typeof(CustomJsonSerializer));
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<CollectionTypeRegistration> CollectionTypeRegistrations { get; protected set; }
    public IEnumerable<InstanceRegistration> InstanceRegistrations { get; protected set; }
}
```

**Q:** *How does this approach differ from creating CustomJsonNetSerializer inheriting from JsonNetSerializer and then registering it in ConfigureApplicationContainer (container.Register( typeof(JsonNetSerializer), typeof(CustomJsonNetSerializer) )?*

**A:** The JsonSerializer is the implementation if json.net for Nancy, this is the recommended method we define on the readme on github:

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy.Serialization.JsonNet#customization

The class you mention is the serialization of an object to JSON, there is another which handles deserialization, both of which utilize JsonSerializer internally:

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy.Serialization.JsonNet/blob/master/src/Nancy.Serialization.JsonNet/JsonNetSerializer.cs#L10

Using this method makes the implementation settings consistent anywhere that the JsonSerializer is used.

**Q:** *can I correctly infer from the approach you've outlined that I would no longer need to explicitly register CustomJsonSerializer in the ConfigureApplicationContainer override in my CustomNancyBootstrapper?*

**A:**  The method I've done for registering is just a cleaner abstraction for registering dependencies, rather than making one giant Bootstrapper, you can create a few smaller specific classes.

Yes using my method means you do not need to register in the bootstrapper.

Comment: Interesting! From my tracing, CollectionTypeRegistrations is where I lost my customizations. Two questions before I try this approach.  How does this approach differ from creating CustomJsonNetSerializer inheriting from JsonNetSerializer and then registering it in ConfigureApplicationContainer (container.Register( typeof(JsonNetSerializer), typeof(CustomJsonNetSerializer) )? Second question, can I correctly infer from the approach you've outlined that I would no longer need to explicitly register CustomJsonSerializer in the ConfigureApplicationContainer override in my CustomNancyBootstrapper?

Comment: Answered your questions in the answer :)

Comment: Awesome insight, big help... Thanks Phill!!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore. The constructor on the custom json serializer never gets called after registering it. Nancy is such a black box...

Comment: @SergeyAkopov why does it need to be re-created over and over? I'm using this method and it still works for me??

Comment: @SergeyAkopov sounds like you're calling the base class after you configure everything so the registration is overridden. So basically. PEBKAC.

Comment: @Phill, my issue was similar. I was registering the serializer too late. Turns out I was registering the custom serializer on per request basis instead of at the application level. This essentially made it undiscoverable.

Comment: @SergeyAkopov glad you solved it. I'll add it to my list of things to do to make clearer documentation. Just need to finish Marten doco first. :)